# PHP short rawurlencode

Tags: php, url

Is there a way to shorten the result of php's [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) 
It is rather long when placed in a link e.g website.php?='rawurlencoderesult'
I would like to be able to shorten the link but still keep the full result for decoding.
The encoding is long because it holds an encrypted value.

Is there a way to do this natively inside PHP. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could compress it before encoding it, but encrypted data doesn't usually compress well. website.php would have to know to decompress it before using it.

Comment: @Barmar Compress then encrypt, what's the problem?

Comment: If it's a block encryption, it may generate a long result even though the input was short.

Comment: `rawurlencode` is not really your problem. Your problem is that your data is long.

Comment: Thanks guys, if I compress before encryption, is there any chance of the data somehow loosing any validity/values, after the link has been clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that your encryption algorithm generates lots of characters that are forbidden in URLs (that is, it outputs a binary string). After URL-encoding them, they basically triple in size as every illegal character is replaced with a `%xx` code.

To avoid this, you need to convert the encrypted value string into the range of URL-allowed characters first, which is `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-_.~`.

One way to do this - albeit inefficient - is to use [`bin2hex()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) (and `hex2bin()` to convert back). It's better to use a conversion function that uses the full range of characters as outlined above, but at this moment I cannot point you to one.

Answer (score 0):

You sort of answer your first question with:

"The encoding is long because it holds an encrypted value."

There are lots of semi-complicated ways of keeping this server-side, it sort of depends on the usage of your links. Personally I'd keep it the way it is, or store the value of "rawurlencoderesult" in a variable via AJAX then have it in a session-variable or within a database.